# Mutt, Gmail and the new mail

Tags: email, imap, mutt

I have my Gmail account accessible via IMAP in Mutt. And I'm probably missing something but why Mutt doesn't marks my email as read when I open it? I mean, in Mutt, I press Enter on an email, it opens -- but if I check it in another email client, the status of this message is still unread.

I even came up a macro like this:

```
macro index    <Return>    "<Enter><sync-mailbox>"    "open, sync mbox"
```

But probably I just really overlooked something, right?

Comment: Can you try ‘ctrl-r’ which is default binding to mark message as read?

Comment: It works. And? :) I mean, my point is to to mark emails as read automatically as I open them, no to press another key combo. So, for now, I'm settled with the macro shown above but may be there's some setting for that?

Comment: try setting this `set mark_old = no` and just open new mail if it works as well.

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't help. And `<Ctrl-r>` wasn't working, too, sorry, I didn't check properly (it marks messages as read but after I exit Mutt and then start it again, they are still unread -- seems like some sync process isn't happening or something). Also, speaking  of `mark_old` -- it seem to be more about `O` / `N` flags, not about the read / unread state, isn't it? Anyway, it's not really a problem, but still thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your `status_char`? It controls whether the mailbox will be synced after closing neomutt or changing mailbox.
You should see it in the beginning of the status line and it should be one of these: `-*%A` If it's not there. try: adding `%r` in `status_format`.  You can change the mailbox status by pressing `%`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ?

Comment: @Hritik, I don't remember actually; I switched to aerc.